# Image scroll in asp.net using foreach

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I was looking at the solution to add image scrolling with arrows from [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/PAw8q/10/)

```
<div class="bloc_1_edito">
<div id="nav_container">
<div id="next_nav">></div>
<div id="prev_nav"><</div>
<div id="nav">

        <li class="activeSlide">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="image_thumbnails" src="http://galaxyfoot.soixanteseize-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/image_edito1.jpg"></img>
            </a>
        </li>
```

but for my project my images come from windows azure so im using foreach syntax as shown below:

view.cshtml -

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<div id="itemView">
    @{
        foreach (var uri in @Model)
        {
            <img class="item" src="@uri" />

        }
    }
</div>
```

Now how do i go about modifying the HTML part above to use li(list item) and  tags as shown in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/PAw8q/10/)

I have searched online for tutorials but all use images stored locally on the system. And i dont know much coding in asp.net as you can see.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below one:

```
<div class="bloc_1_edito">
<div id="nav_container">
    <div id="next_nav">></div>
    <div id="prev_nav"><</div>
    <div id="nav">
    @{
        var index=0;
        foreach (var uri in @Model)
        {
            if(index==0)//check if it is first image
            {
               <li class="activeSlide"> //If yes add activeSlide to first li
                   <a href="#">
                      <img class="image_thumbnails" src="@uri"/>
                  </a>
               </li>
            }
            else
            {
               <li>
                   <a href="#">
                      <img class="image_thumbnails" src="@uri"/>
                  </a>
               </li>
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thnx for the quick reply. but now only the first image appears. the rest of the images not showing up.

Comment: just place a debugger and see what you are getting. whether the control is going to else part or not and if possible please show what your @Model contains and how you are assigning data to your model

Comment: how do i debug in cshtml? i am unable to add breakpoints. And also in the cshtml when i am adding the javascript do i need to add any source for it?

Comment: nope not coming. im updating my visual studio. ill try then. even intellisense doesnt in cshtml for me.

Comment: Yea!! Let me know then!

Comment: i still cant get the breakpoints in any of the cshtml files. any other workaround?

Comment: ok so i tried the exact same code as in jsfiddle. the same css file the same html file the same javascript but even the navigation doesnt work. is there something i am missing? do i have to add some script source or some thing to make it work in asp.net visual studio?

Comment: ok so i checked in jsfiddle that when i dont select jquery edge the scrolling doesnt work. so i just need to include the jquery edge library right?

Comment: Can you post the fiddle? Check also if you are getting any console error in browser?

Comment: so the jsfiddle link is the same as above: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PAw8q/10/
and no im not getting any console error as such.

Comment: You need to include `jquery.js` file.. any latest version!! not a matter of adding `jquery edge`

Comment: so basically i was doing it in the wrong view; as i have one view and one partial view within this view. 
And then i put this in the view - <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
and then within the body tag i put the javascript. And it works. thnx a lot for your help.

Comment: Cool.. Do not forget to accept this as answer if it helped you so that people who visit here next time will find this useful.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is asp.net MVC (.cshtml) and not asp.net (.aspx).

You could directly add the li tag inside the foreach

```
 @{
        Layout = null;
    }


    <div id="itemView">
        @{
            foreach (var uri in @Model)
            {
             <li>
                <img class="item" src="@uri" />
             </li>

            }
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: yes im using mvc, but i cannot seem to get the remaining images. only the first image appears. Do i need to include a source for the javascript?